# jQuery disable, and enable bxslider on window resize

Tags: jquery, resize

I've got some problem with bxslider.
I want to disable it when user resize the window under 1051px and enable again when user resize over 1051px.

this is what i've got:

```
var slider =
    $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
      minSlides: 4,
      maxSlides: 4,
      moveSlides: 1,
      slideWidth: 310,
      slideMargin: 1
    });

$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(this).width() > 1051 ) {
        slider;
    } else {
        slider.destroySlider();
    }
});
```

it's the best solution i found so far, beacouse it disables bxslider, but it wouldn't enable it again.

I've also tryied to put th bxslider function into a function, but that fires bxslider multiple times, and create a mess.

Comment: why don't you use css3 media query. It will be easier than using javascript and is also purposed for responsive design just like what you want to achieve using jquery.

Comment: @SoursopTree not really i think... i wan't to disable all .bxslider functions... and i cannot do it by css3

Comment: try this:

    `var setting = {
          minSlides: 4,
          maxSlides: 4,
          moveSlides: 1,
          slideWidth: 310,
          slideMargin: 1
        };
    
    var slider = $('.bxslider2').bxSlider(setting);
    
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(this).width() > 1051 ) {
            slider.bxSlider(setting);
        } else {
            slider.destroySlider();
        }
    });`

Comment: unfortunettly this is working same way as putting $('.bxslider2').bxSlider into a function... it's making another slide every 1 piksel of window resize...